# Clean an svn checkout (remove non-svn files)

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

Id like to remove all files in my working copy that are not known in the svn repository.

Effectively as if I'd just made a clean checkout, but Id rather not have to re-download all files.

The closest think I've come to this is...

```
rm -rf `svn st | grep "^?" | cut -d" " -f8`
```

But this seems clunky and I don't totally trust it since inconsistency in output could remove dirs outside svn.

"svn export" isn't what Im looking for because I'm not cleaning the source to package it, I just want to remove cruft mostly (*.pyc, *.orig, *.rej, svn-commit.tmp, *.swp).

Is there a better way to do this besides making a clean checkout?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239340/automatically-remove-subversion-unversioned-files)

Comment: (per @rodion) possible duplicate of [Automatically Remove Subversion Unversioned Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239340/automatically-remove-subversion-unversioned-files)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Most solutions that are posted here fail to handle folders with whitespaces. This is why we use this one:

```
svn status --no-ignore | grep '^[?I]' |  sed "s/^[?I] //" | xargs -I{} rm -rf "{}"
```

Comment: Great minds think alike. This is the perfect command-line to accomplish that feat.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.cuberick.com/2008/11/clean-up-your-subversion-working-copy.html

> Here is what I do when I want my working copy to be identical to the repo:

```
 svn st | awk '{print $2}' | xargs rm -rf
```

> That will remove all files that are out of sync with the repository. Then simply update to restore things you deleted and get up to date.

```
svn up
```

> ... Make sure that you've no edits or adds! Safer command might be:

```
svn st | grep '?' | awk '{print $2}' |xargs rm -f
```

> ... What about ignored files? E.g.

```
svn st --no-ignore
svn st --no-ignore | awk '{print $2}' | xargs rm -rf
svn st --no-ignore | grep '?' | awk '{print $2}' |xargs rm -f
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that your commands with `awk` will fail if there are spaces in file names, because `awk`  will only grab the second "field", which might be just the first word in a file/folder name. `rm` will fail to find the file/folder.

Answer (score 3):

```
svn status --no-ignore | grep '^[?I]' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs rm -rf
```

Let me explain.

Get the status of the files in a repository and prints them out one by one to standard output into an array

```
svn status
```

This includes files set to normally be ignored by svn

```
--no-ignore
```

Match lines that include either a ? or a I as a status.  I means an ignored file and ? means a file not under svn control.

```
| grep '^[?I]'
```

This prints the second variable in the array which is the filename

```
| awk '{print $2}'
```

This removes the files with the printed filesnames

```
| xargs rm -rf
```

Cheers,
Loop

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
svn status --no-ignore | grep ^I | awk '{print $2}' | xargs rm -rf
```

Obtained from [commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1436/svn-clean).

Answer (score -2):

Delete every file that doesn't have the readonly attribute? Make sure you don't have things checked out beforehands...

Comment: thejohndonson to the rescue ))) And that is what question is about - how to do that automatically :-))

Comment: Since when does SVN apply the readonly attribute to all files in the checkout?  I thought that kind of misbehavior was TFS territory.