# Why does SVN sometimes report unversioned files as skipped, and sometimes not?

Tags: svn, command-line, version-control, nested, revert

When running `svn revert -R *` command from repository root, sometimes I get unversioned files reported as "Skipped", but sometimes I don't. When it reports unversioned files, the output is like

```
Skipped 'path/to/file/name.ext'
```

When it doesn't report unversioned files as skipped, it just doesn't output anything about unversioned files.

For the sake of scripting I would like all unversioned files (and only unversioned files) to be reported as skipped.

This is for the purpose of removing unversioned files, while the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239340/automatically-remove-subversion-unversioned-files) doesn't work for nested SVN repositories because they are also listed with `?` leading character by `svn status`.

UPDATE:
`svn st -v` produces output like the following:

```
?                                        projects/test-suite
            281978   239612 gbedwell     resources
            281978   239612 gbedwell     resources/windows_version_resource.rc
            281978   281585 hahnfeld     runtimes
            281978   281585 hahnfeld     runtimes/CMakeLists.txt
            281978   279776 cbieneman    runtimes/Components.cmake.in
?                                        t1.txt
```

In the bottom there is unversioned file I want to get reported as "Skipped" (and consequently, to remove this file with a script). In the top there is a nested repository, whose status is indistinguishable from the status of an unversioned file. I wouldn't like to remove the nested repository in the script.

This time `svn revert -R *`reports the unversioned file as skipped, here is the full output:

```
Skipped 't1.txt'
```

UPDATE2: It seems that when the command is like `svn revert -R repository`, svn doesn't list the unversioned files as skipped. But when the command is like `svn revert -R repository/*`, it lists. Though I'm not sure if this is the only cause, I think the latter command type sometimes did not list too unversioned files as skipped.

Comment: Is there any real output sample?

Comment: @bahrep, when it says "Skipped" the real output is as in the above example, just the file path&name are different. When it doesn't say "Skipped", it just doesn't output anything.

Comment: It's interesting to see `svn st -v` output and full output of `svn revert -R *` and learn about configured `svn:ignore`s

Comment: @bahrep, I've included the outputs. How to get the info about `svn:ignore`s you ask for?