# How to write svn shell script in centos

Tags: svn, centos, sh

I have a website in CentOS which uses SVN to update and commit.

I want to write a shell script by crontab to auto run schedule work.

I have test a SVN command, **svn status | grep ^?**
It shows me results like below:

```
M index.php<br/>
M data/config.php<br/>
? date/aaa.php<br/>
? images/bbb.php<br/>
? images/product1.jpg<br/>
? images/product2.jpg<br/>
? themes/ccc.php<br/>
? themes/index.html<br/>
? temp/compiled/index.php<br/>
? temp/compiled/article.php<br/>
? temp/compiled/footer.php<br/>
```

I write a SVN command which can delete all unversion and modify php file, like below:

**svn status --no-ignore | grep ".php$" | sed 's/^?     //'  | xargs rm -rf**

I want to write a shell script that can help me:

- **delete the unversion file, except modify file**
- **only delete php file**
- **excepte file ine temp folder**

please help me, thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use grep with the option `-v` to exclude file paths under temp. To make the command safer I would also skip `-r` and `-f` in the `rm` command:

```
svn status --no-ignore | grep '^?.*\.php$' | grep -v '^? *temp/' | sed 's/^? *//' | xargs rm
```

Comment: Remember that `grep 'x' | sed 's/y/z/'` can be refactored to `sed -n '/x/s/y/z/p'`. You can also easily get rid of the last `grep` with a similar refactoring. See also [useless use of `grep`.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Comment: @tripleee Apart from conciseness and efficiency we also need to consider readability for someone who is not a sed expert (like me). Another readable alternative is to use awk.

Comment: I've a computer which is windows system.
How to do the same work in windows bat?

Comment: @Breakgod See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127318/is-there-any-sed-like-utility-for-cmd-exe

Comment: I've read sed, but I don't have any idea to write this command .

Comment: @Breakgod Here are some useful alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239340/automatically-remove-subversion-unversioned-files/239358